# Transfer the same values ​in the dictionary to another dictionary and save database

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

This is how orders are kept in the dictionary.

I want to keep the same seller values ​​in the dictionary in another dictionary. and separately I want to save it as order in database.

Orders:

```
{
    "1": {"image": "67021f123f31ab63834f.jpg", "name": "Chai", "price": 18.0, "quantity": "1", "seller": "2"}, 
    "24": {"image": "", "name": "Guaran\u00e1 Fant\u00e1stica", "price": 4.5, "quantity": "1", "seller": "2"}, 
    "3": {"image": "", "name": "Aniseed Syrup", "price": 10.0, "quantity": "1", "seller": "10"}
}
```

If the seller values ​​are the same, I want it to be like this.

```
{
    "1": {"image": "67021f123f31ab63834f.jpg", "name": "Chai", "price": 18.0, "quantity": "1", "seller": "2"}, 
    "24": {"image": "", "name": "Guaran\u00e1 Fant\u00e1stica", "price": 4.5, "quantity": "1", "seller": "2"}
}

{
    "3": {"image": "", "name": "Aniseed Syrup", "price": 10.0, "quantity": "1", "seller": "10"}
}
```

how can i separate dictionaries like this..

**i am new here. Sorry for my language mistakes and other mistakes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary whose keys are sellers, and values are these nested dictionaries.

```
from collections import defaultdict

sellers = default_dict(dict)

for orderid, order in orders.items():
    sellers[order['seller']][orderid] = order
```

Comment: Sir thank u for answering my question. I have a last question. How do I save the orders separately in the database. How can I check the Seller id of 2 as a separate record and the 10 as a separate record.

Comment: For the second you can do `if "10" in sellers["2"]:` to check if the order ID is in a seller.

Comment: You save these in the database the same way you save anything else. I don't see why you would need to split it up before saving, since the seller ID and order ID should just be columns in the table.

Comment: There are multiple seller and how can I dynamically control this?

Comment: Seller ids are not kept in the table as a column. For later invoicing, I need to keep the products from each order in the database by sellers.

Comment: Where are seller IDs kept if they're not in a column? If it's not a column, how do you know which seller is associated with each product?

Comment: The seller of the product is kept in the "CreatorID" column in the products table. When the user adds the product to the cart, there is the CreatorID of the product in the 'seller' section of session['Shoppingcart'].

Comment: When you do the invoicing you should join with the `products` table to get the seller. Don't reproduce it in the order table.

Comment: This is how orders are kept in the database : 

order = CustomerOrder(name = name , lastname = lastname, invoice = invoice, address1 = address1, address2 = address2, city = city, state = state , zip = zip_code, customer_id = customer_id, orders = session['Shoppingcart'])

The content of session['Shoppingcart'] is also the json structure I gave in the question.

I want to save the products in an order by seller to the database.

Comment: I'm not going to answer a question in comments. Please post a new question that shows your table schema and asks how to store this.

Comment: Sure, thank you for your interest and help sir.